# I want get maplist but there is still error for do not have value

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, slick, slick-2.0

I use scala+play2+slick2:

```
val subject = TableQuery[Subjects]
```

subject is my tableQuery

in controller I defined a functional:

```
import scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._
def index = DBAction {implicit rs =>

Ok(views.html.list_subject.render("Hello from Scala", (subject.drop(0).map(i => (i.id, i.name, i.describe,i.sub_resource)).run)
    ))
}
```

the error is:

```
[info] Loading project definition from G:\testprojects\slickplay\project
[info] Set current project to slickplay (in build file:/G:/testprojects/slickpla
y/)
[info] Compiling 6 Scala sources to G:\testprojects\slickplay\target\scala-2.10\
classes...
[error] G:\testprojects\slickplay\app\controllers\MainController.scala:12: could
not find implicit value for parameter session: scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend#Ses
sionDef
[error]     Ok(views.html.list_subject.render("Hello from Scala", (subject.drop(
0).map(i => (i.id, i.name, i.describe,i.sub_resource)).run)
[error]
                                                   ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 9 s, completed 11/04/2014 2:23:57 PM
```

Is there any example with scala+play2+slick2 and use Form? Any one know how to return the 
(i.id, i.name, i.describe,i.sub_resource) list?

Comment: @cvogt still need help for the errors

Comment: You need to debug situations like this by manually applying the implicit conversion and seeing what's going wrong on the way. Try `.run(rs.dbSession)` and post the output please.

Comment: @cvogt Thanks. it is this problem and it works

Comment: You shouldn't need to type `.run(rs.dbSession)`. You are using the wrong imports. Look at Adi's answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try importing

```
import play.api.db.slick._
import play.api.db.slick.Config.driver.simple._
```

if you are using DBAction, which I presume from [play-slick plugin](https://github.com/freekh/play-slick/wiki/Usage)